# Find files between specific timestamp in Oracle Solaris 11.4

Tags: timestamp, command, range, solaris

I am trying to find files from yesterday 12.30 AM till today 12.29 AM and cat them in a single file. However the newermt command is not working and it might be due to my OS. I am working on Solaris 11.4. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the newermt command is not working"?  That's not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the `-newermt` option is not recognized by `find`, that means the SVR4 `find` command is the one appearing first in your PATH.

A simple way to overcome the issue is to explicitely run `GNU find` which is required for this non standard option.

```
/usr/gnu/bin/find ... -newermt ...
```